# Displaying the elements in a list of expressions

Tags: prolog

I have a list containing expressions of the form: a-I-J-K (those are not expressions but rather a codification of variables, but that's not the point for this question).

I want to write every expression in the list by using the following code:

```
display(L) :- member(p-I-J-K, L), write(I), nl, fail.
display(_).
```

With this, I'm trying to make Prolog unify p-I-J-K with all the elements in L, and it works, because it prints them. The only problem is that this code keeps printing the elements in a loop that doesn't stop, and I can't really understand why.

In the example I'm just writing I to illustrate the problem, in the real problem I'm writing a meaningful string.

So basically, why does this code never stop, and what would be the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not reproducible. The following executes with `swipl` just nicely:

```
:- initialization(main).

d(L) :- member(p-I-J-K, L), write(I), nl, fail.
d(_).

main :- d([p-a-c-k,p-o-l-l,p-i-c-k]),halt.
```

prints 'a', 'o', 'i' on separate lines. Please post a runnable example, ideally a stand-alone script that does not require any messing around with the interactive interpreter.

The proper way to do it would be not to reinvent square wheels in the first place:

```
foreach(member(p-I-J-K, L), write(I))
```

should do it.